# How to import Scanner into a class called System

Tags: java

This is the code I am trying to execute, class name is SystemTest as it is required for part of a project:

```
public class SystemTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int optionSelect;

        java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        optionSelect = sc.nextInt();

    }

}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    in cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at SystemTest.main(SystemTest.java:15)
```

To be more specific, the `in` of `System.in` is underlined with the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner;`

Comment: Kindly reimport `Scanner` first remove this `java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);` line press `ctr+shift+o` after import `Scanner`.

Comment: This issue is not reproducible as is.

Comment: Your import is valid. You could import your Scanner before your class declaration if you wish, but this won't solve the problem.

Comment: You might want to go through the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). It's Java 8, but it covers the basics well, and you need a lot of help with the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new java.util.Scanner(java.lang.System.in);`

Answer (score 2):

Don't name your classes with the same names as the ones in the `java.lang` package.

Since that package is automatically imported `System.in` normally refers to the JDK class, but now it will refer to **your** `System` class, requiring you to use the **fully qualified name** `java.lang.System` to refer to the JDK class.

This easily causes confusion, as Java programmers expect `System` to mean `java.lang.System`. If you can't come up with a great name, the `MySystem` naming style works for hobby projects.

You should also use imports to avoid specifying the FQN everywhere, like you're doing with `Scanner` in your code.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion! The reason for the name is it is a university task, so I am stuck with this class name. I will keep this as a reference for future projects.